# What test case could break this solution to the Incl/Excl principle challenge?

Tags: java, algorithm

I was working on a programming challenge, and one of the questions involve an inclusion/exclusion principle problem that I thought I have fixed, but kept failing some of the test cases. I can't think of what they might be (2 of the test cases fail, but they don't show the output). Can you give me some ideas on what they might be?

The original problem:

> K caterpillars are eating their way through N leaves, each caterpillar
>   falls from leaf to leaf in a unique sequence, all caterpillars start
>   at a twig at position 0 and falls onto the leaves at position between
>   1 and N. Each caterpillar j has as associated jump number Aj. A
>   caterpillar with jump number j eats leaves at positions that are
>   multiple of j. It will proceed in the order j, 2j, 3j…. till it
>   reaches the end of the leaves and it stops and build its cocoon. Given
>   a set A of K elements K<-15, N<=10^9, we need to determine the number
>   of uneaten leaves.
>
> *Input:*
>
> N = No of uneaten leaves K = No. of caterpillars A = Array of integer
>   jump numbers
>
> *Output:*
>
> The integer nu. Of uneaten leaves
>
> *Sample Input:*
>
> 10 3 2 4 5
>
> *Output:*
>
> 4
>
> *Explanation:*
>
> [2, 4, 5] is a j member jump numbers, all leaves which are multiple of
>   2, 4, and 5 are eaten, leaves 1,3,7,9 are left, and thus the no. 4

My solution:

```
static int countUneatenLeaves(int N, int[] A) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        int multiplier = (int) Math.pow(-1, i);
        total += multiplier * combination(A, i + 1, N);
    }
    return N - total;
}

public static int combination(int[] elements, int K, int num) {

    // get the length of the array
    // e.g. for {'A','B','C','D'} => N = 4 
    int N = elements.length;

    // get the combination by index 
    // e.g. 01 --> AB , 23 --> CD
    int combination[] = new int[K];

    // position of current index
    //  if (r = 1)              r*
    //  index ==>       0   |   1   |   2
    //  element ==>     A   |   B   |   C
    int r = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int total = 0;
    while (r >= 0) {
        // possible indexes for 1st position "r=0" are "0,1,2" --> "A,B,C"
        // possible indexes for 2nd position "r=1" are "1,2,3" --> "B,C,D"

        // for r = 0 ==> index < (4+ (0 - 2)) = 2
        if (index <= (N + (r - K))) {
            combination[r] = index;

            // if we are at the last position print and increase the index
            if (r == K - 1) {

                //do something with the combination e.g. add to list or print
                total += calc(combination, elements, num);
                index++;
            } else {
                // select index for next position
                index = combination[r] + 1;
                r++;
            }
        } else {
            r--;
            if (r > 0) index = combination[r] + 1;
            else index = combination[0] + 1;
        }
    }
    return total;
}

private static int calc(int[] combination, int[] elements, int num) {

    int eaten = 0;
    if (combination.length == 1) {
        eaten = (int) Math.floor(num / elements[combination[0]]);
    } else {
        int lcm = lcm(elements[combination[0]], elements[combination[1]]);
        for (int i = 2; i < combination.length; i++) {
            lcm = lcm(lcm, elements[combination[i]]);
        }
        eaten = Math.abs((int) Math.floor(num / lcm));
    }
    return eaten;
}

private static int lcm(int a, int b) {
    return a * (b / findGCD(a, b));
}

private static int findGCD(int number1, int number2) {
    //base case
    if (number2 == 0) {
        return number1;
    }

    return findGCD(number2, number1 % number2);
}
```

I tried many test inputs myself but failed to find the case where it breaks. I suspect the test that fails involves large N, as if I go for a simple brute force approach, the same test cases fail with time out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Null array inputs. Maybe not the immediate case that is failing, but it would cause an NPE.

Comment: Can some one help with the  same question in php?Is data types required in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use long to instead of int. Because the element of A can be closer to 10^9. So when num gcd(a, b) is small, such as 1, the lcm(a, b) = a * b may be larger than 0x7FFFFFFF, so the answer is not correct.